# Cannot access django app through ip address while accessing it through localhost

Tags: python, django, networking

I have a django app on my local computer. I can access the application from a browser by using the url: http://localhost:8000/myapp/

But I cannot access the application by using the ip of the host computer: http://193.140.209.49:8000/myapp/ I get a 404 error.

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I assume you're using the development server.  If so, then you need to specifically bind to your external IP for the server to be available there.  Try this command:

```
./manage.py runserver 193.140.209.49:8000
```

Comment: Or you can use 0.0.0.0:8000 to bind to the computer's external IP address whatever it is.

Comment: 0.0.0.0:8000 binds to all interfaces, not just the external one, so it can still be accessed as localhost:8000

Comment: `0:8000` also works, as a shorter spelling of `0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: @EdwardDale it works fine but after that I can only access my server using system IP and if I trying to access using localhost so server not responding.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I had to do as below:

- To run App in Local LAN *

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
http://localhost:8000
http://127.0.0.1:8000
http://192.168.0.99:8000
```

- To run App with Public IP *

Port 8080 would not work for me and so I had to add Port 8081.

Add port 8081 in Windows Defender (Inbound Rules)

Add port 8081 in the Internet Router's Virtual Servers

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8081
http://103.122.xxx.xx:8081
```

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '103.122.xxx.xx', '192.168.0.99']
```

I am sure that there could be a better method. As of now this works for me in ***Visual Studio Code***.