# Visit webpage hosted on ubuntu server in a local network

Tags: django, networking, ubuntu, web

I have a ubuntu server hosting a web page driven by Python Django, I can access that page by using the following command:elinks http:// 127.0.0.1:8000.

Now if I want to access that same web page on a macbook sharing the same home router with my ubuntu server(local ip: 10.0.0.9), how would I do it? Typing in elinks http:// 10.0.0.9:8000 wouldn't work.

Thanks a lot,
ZZ

Comment: Are you serving files via Nginx? Maybe you have your configuration wrong. A little more info would be great.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493479/cannot-access-django-app-through-ip-address-while-accessing-it-through-localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve it. There are a number of ways to do this, but my preferred method is to use [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) as a reverse proxy server for [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). [This](http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/) is a good tutorial for that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the development server using manage.py?

If so, you should start the server using:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This will allow the development server to be visited by ips on all interfaces instead of just localhost.