# Unable to view my django and react website on ec2

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I have been trying to host my react and django application on AWS EC2. The approach I was following is that to deploy both the servers and be able to access them by http://ec2publicip:3000 for react and http://ec2publicip:8000 for django.

I want to be able to test my website on the ec2 website before I purchase a domain and have both my servers as subdomains.

I launched the ec2 instance and then git cloned my repo, which contains both the react and django applications. I successfully installed all the requirements and when I run my django server, on the terminal it shows that its been activated, but when I go to http://ec2publicip:8000 I just get that it took to long to respond on my web browser

I have followed the following guide [https://www.programink.com/django-tutorial/django-deployment.html] but I have had no success

Attaching my git hub repo link just in case since I don't think there is a problem with the code as I have been running the same on my local machine, and its working fine https://github.com/revanthperla/platform_test.git

Any help or pointers would be appreciated

Comment: How did you run you Django server? If you're using runserver and you're accessing it via IP you need to specify that when running: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493479/cannot-access-django-app-through-ip-address-while-accessing-it-through-localhost

Comment: Ok I tied that after looking at your comment, and I get this error Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you didn't configure inbound rules in AWS for your ec2, please refer to AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html).

or follow this guide [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/opening-port-3000-on-ec2-instance-a-stepbystep-guide/) to open port 3000 or 8000.

Comment: I have configured the following inbound rules
Port 22 - SSH - 0.0.0.0/0
Port 80 - HTTP - 0.0.0.0/0
Port 443 - HTTPS - 0.0.0.0/0
Port 8000 - Custom TCP - ::/0

I am still facing the same issue

Comment: do you have an active firewall on your instance? 

if you're using Ubuntu check it with ufw status

Comment: When I check the ufw status it shows its inactive

Comment: are you sure your django or react apps are actually running and serving data? 

try to use python-http server to check: python3 -m http.server